# how to create task in c++?

Tags: c++, winapi, scheduled-tasks

I want to create a c++ program that can relaunch itself or other program with high privilege bypassing UAC dialog.

Comment: This kind of stuff is usually a lot easier with a scripting language...

Comment: I'm unclear if you want a fix for the compiler error or help with creating the task..

Comment: The compiler is presenting you with a WARNING not an ERROR. The same as @dew1 I am unclear what you want help with.

Comment: @jwpfox _Line Error C4996 '_wgetenv':_  pretty sure it's set to actually error out

Comment: Sorry - yes I am being confusingly unclear - the OP has set the compiler to present warnings as errors. If they don't want that behaviour they can disable it. Thanks for making it clearer @deW1.

Comment: is there a solution in c++? or in scripting language??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find `notepad.exe` in the Windows system directory, I'd advise just doing that a little more directly:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main() { 
    char path[_MAX_PATH];

    GetSystemDirectory(path, sizeof(path));

    strcat_s(path, "/notepad.exe");

    WinExec(path, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
}
```

To execute the result under a specified user account, you normally want to use `CreateProcessWithLogonW` (there are a few alternatives such as `CreateProcessAsUser` and `CreateProcessWithTokenW`, but `CreateProcessWithLogonW` is usually preferred).

This uses wide characters, so it's probably easiest to use wide characters throughout, something like this:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

template <size_t N>
DWORD GetSystemDirectory(wchar_t (&buffer)[N]) {
    return GetSystemDirectoryW(buffer, N);
}

template <size_t N>
void append(wchar_t (&buffer)[N], wchar_t const *src) {
    wcscat_s(buffer, N, src);
}

int main() { 
    wchar_t path[_MAX_PATH];

    GetSystemDirectory(path);

    append(path, L"/Notepad.exe");

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    CreateProcessWithLogonW(L"Username", L"machine_name", L"password", 0, path, NULL, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, NULL, &pi);
}
```

Comment: but I want to run notepad for example with high privilege

Comment: @raindrop7: go ahead. Your question seemed to be about the part where you retrieve the path to notepad.exe, and this shows how to do that cleanly. Did you intend to ask a second question about how to execute a program under a different user account as well?

Comment: your program cannot open application those need elevation?! let's say "diskraid.exe" which need elevation

Comment: @raindrop7: Of course. The whole point of a security model is to make it hard to get around it. Windows undoubtedly isn't perfect, but it's not going to make it *this* easy to bypass security requirements. You may be able to get what you want with a combination of `LogonUser` and one of the other `CreateProcess*` functions mentioned in the answer.